# Create a user for a known login on every new database created on Azure SQL?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

Is there a good way to automate creating a new user and adding it as a DB owner on every new database created on an Azure-hosted SQL Server?

so basically create user + alter role db_owner add member (or sp_addrolemember) every time a new database is created on the server.

TL;DR on 'why' : I need to have every database on the server accessible (and editable, change schema objects, change data, etc) with a user attached to a specific login, relating to [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-mssql/issues/998) issue.

Comment: Check this page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql) and this page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-role-transact-sql)

Comment: @EstienneGranet Those talk about the actual SQL needed to do this manually, per-database, indeed. But i was asking about automating for every new database on the server, rather than doing so manually. Unless I'm missing something in those links, That's not going to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I tried checking with ARM templates to see if there is a possibilty of editing templates to add users..But there is [no option at present](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins).Read comments section for more info..

If the logical server name is same for all the databases.. you could try using [azure functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scenario-database-table-cleanup) and loop each db and use execute non query method..

you can set to run this function every one hour or 12 hours and also it should check if that user status before creating